# Call Navigation/Maps/Drive with an Address in WP8.1 Application

Tags: c#, navigation, maps, windows-phone-8.1, drive

I was wondering if it's possible to call the default navigation application within my Windows Phone 8.1 application. I have an address and I would like for the user to press a button and be able to navigate to that address through the default navigation app. If this is possible, how do I do it?

Thanks for your time,

Johan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch turn-by-turn directions apps using the [ms-drive-to and ms-walk-to schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (depending on the type of directions you want) but you first need to get a geocoordinate for the address that you have. Since you're targeting Windows Phone 8.1, you can use the [MapLocationFinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.services.maps.maplocationfinder.aspx) class in the Windows.Services.Maps namespace.

```
string locationName = "Empire State Building";
string address = "350 5th Avenue, New York City, New York 10018";

var locFinderResult = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(
    address, new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()));

// add error checking here

var geoPos = locFinderResult.Locations[0].Point.Position;

var driveToUri = new Uri(String.Format(
     "ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude={0}&destination.longitude={1}&destination.name={2}", 
     geoPos.Latitude, 
     geoPos.Longitude, 
     locationName));

Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(driveToUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

the official solution is:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=" + latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
            "&destination.longitude=" + longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

        if (success)
        {
            // Uri launched.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
```

But, there is a problem with this solution.

If you use the nokia programs (HERE), it works fine.

if you want to use waze, you have to add origin.latitude and origin.longitude.

in the MSDN page, They said that it is not necessary, but in fact, you have to write it.

I am already not enable to load moovit but if someone has an issue, it'll help me a lot.

Comment: this is another answer, more effective with waze

Comment: Sounds more like a bug with Waze that they haven't implemented the schema correctly...